# flask insert html file and variables into jinja2 template

Tags: flask, jinja2

In tornado I am to do the following in a template:

```
{% block foo %}
   {% module Template("foo.html", arg=42) %}
{% end %}.
```

I am wondering if there is a Flask equivalent?

Here `{% module *expr* %}` imports the template file and passes a variable. It seems to be similar to how Flask would passes a variable in the view.py.

```
@app.route("/foo")
def foo():
    return render_template("foo.html", arg=42)
```

Comment: And what does `module` *do* in Tornado?

Comment: Thanks Sean. How would you pass a variable with the include? I'm doing this now `{% set active = "index" %}{% include "navigation.html" %}`